# Switching profiles to "do not disturb" for multiple tools

Tags: windows, gratis, offline

In my company, different teams use different messaging tools. In total, I have Discord, MS Teams, Zoom and ProCall. At home, stuff is not much different. I use Skype, MS Teams and Discord.

When I want to focus on a task to get it done, I usually switch to "do not disturb" - but I always forget one tool. Therefore I am looking for a utility that can switch all my messengers to "do not disturb" (and back) in one go.

The tool should work on Windows 10 x64 and be free of cost (gratis; open source preferred) and work offline. It should at least support Discord, Teams, Skye and Zoom. Not sure if ProCall is a widely known thing someone would program for.

Comment: Hi Thomas.  I have a hunch you may have a hard time finding such a tool (but good idea for one!).  Have you thought about using a scripting tool such as AutoHotkey, AutoIt, or NirSoft's NirCmd?

Comment: My upvote pushed you over 10,000 points!  Congrats!  Now, to draw a little attention to your accomplishment... https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3024/congratulations-to-thomas-weller